# Display dataframe columns repeatedly for each pivot value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` I'd like to reshape:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jon', 'jon', 'karen', 'karen'], 'weekday': ['sun', 'mon','sun', 'mon'], 'hour': [9,10, 9, 10],'calls': [4,5, 9, 10], 'emails': [10,11,7,9], 'sms': [3,4,5,4]})
```

If I `groupby` 'name', 'weekday', 'hour' (and take the max) I get a frame in my pre-pivot shape:

```
In [48]: groupdf = df.groupby(['name', 'weekday', 'hour']).max()

Out[49]: 
                    calls  emails  sms
name  weekday hour                    
jon   mon     10        5      11    4
      sun     9         4      10    3
      tues    11        7      12    5
karen mon     10       10       9    4
      sun     9         9       7    5
      tues    11       12       8    3

In [50]:
```

What I want is `calls`, `emails`, `sms` totals repeated for each hour of the of the weekday, like so:

```
              9                    10                  11
                 calls  emails sms    calls emails sms    calls emails sms
name weekday
jon    sun         4      10    3       0     0     0      0      0       0
```

The closest I can get is by doing `unstack`

```
In [54]: groupdf.unstack('hour', fill_value=0)
Out[54]: 
              calls         emails         sms      
hour             9   10  11     9   10  11  9  10 11
name  weekday                                       
jon   mon         0   5   0      0  11   0   0  4  0
      sun         4   0   0     10   0   0   3  0  0
      tues        0   0   7      0   0  12   0  0  5
karen mon         0  10   0      0   9   0   0  4  0
      sun         9   0   0      7   0   0   5  0  0
      tues        0   0  12      0   0   8   0  0  3
```

which gets me close but not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table) with `max` as the `aggfunc` to go straight from `df` then [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html#pandas-dataframe-swaplevel) and [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-index):

```
p = (
    df.pivot_table(index=['name', 'weekday'],
                   columns='hour',
                   values=['emails', 'calls', 'sms'],
                   aggfunc='max',
                   fill_value=0)
        .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
        .sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
)
```

Or [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas-dataframe-unstack) + [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html#pandas-dataframe-swaplevel) + [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-index) from `groupdf`:

```
groupdf = df.groupby(['name', 'weekday', 'hour']).max()
groupdf = (
    groupdf
        .unstack('hour', fill_value=0)
        .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
        .sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
)
```

Both produce:

```
hour             9                10               11           
              calls emails sms calls emails sms calls emails sms
name  weekday                                                   
jon   mon         0      0   0     5     11   4     0      0   0
      sun         4     10   3     0      0   0     0      0   0
      tues        0      0   0     0      0   0     7     12   5
karen mon         0      0   0    10      9   4     0      0   0
      sun         9      7   5     0      0   0     0      0   0
      tues        0      0   0     0      0   0    12      8   3
```

From:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jon', 'jon', 'jon', 'karen', 'karen', 'karen'],
                   'weekday': ['sun', 'mon', 'tues', 'sun', 'mon', 'tues'],
                   'hour': [9, 10, 11, 9, 10, 11],
                   'calls': [4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12],
                   'emails': [10, 11, 12, 7, 9, 8],
                   'sms': [3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3]})
```

```
    name weekday  hour  calls  emails  sms
0    jon     sun     9      4      10    3
1    jon     mon    10      5      11    4
2    jon    tues    11      7      12    5
3  karen     sun     9      9       7    5
4  karen     mon    10     10       9    4
5  karen    tues    11     12       8    3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `.reindex` the unstacked grouped dataframe:

```py
groupdf = df.groupby(["name", "weekday", "hour"]).max()

# construct multiindex:
a = sorted(groupdf.index.get_level_values("hour").unique())
b = groupdf.columns
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a, b])

# reindex unstacked dataframe:
x = groupdf.unstack("hour").swaplevel(axis=1).fillna(0)
x = x.reindex(idx, axis=1)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
                 9                 10            
              calls emails  sms calls emails  sms
name  weekday                                    
jon   mon       0.0    0.0  0.0   5.0   11.0  4.0
      sun       4.0   10.0  3.0   0.0    0.0  0.0
karen mon       0.0    0.0  0.0  10.0    9.0  4.0
      sun       9.0    7.0  5.0   0.0    0.0  0.0
```